# OpenSessionInView isn't starting, spring, hibernate

Tags: spring, hibernate, open-session-in-view

Hi everyone I have a problem with OpenSessionInViewFilter, this filter isn't starting at all.
It's third day my torture with this, I don't have any ideas how to solve it, I have read many many questions and answer about this but nothing helped me.
There are my config files, I have two projects, first with services needed in second (web app).

In first project in web.xml I have:

```
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
                  http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
version="3.0">
<display-name>O4B remoting service</display-name>

<filter>
    <filter-name>OpenSessionInViewFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>sessionFactoryBeanName</param-name>
        <param-value>hibernateSessionFactory</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>OpenSessionInViewFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath*:spring-config.xml</param-value>
</context-param>


<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
</listener>





<servlet>
    <servlet-name>accountActivationServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>xxx.xxx.service.user.AccountActivationServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>accountActivationServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/activate</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

In this project I have spring-config.xml:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util" xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xsi:schemaLocation="
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/util 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/task 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.0.xsd">

<context:annotation-config />

<import resource="spring-remoting-xxx-service-exporter.xml" />
<import resource="classpath*:spring-hibernate.xml"/>

<bean id="xmlConfigurationDefault" class="xxx.xxx.applicationCommons.spring.SpringXMLConfiguration">
    <constructor-arg type="org.springframework.core.io.Resource"
        value="classpath:configuration.xml" />
    <property name="throwExceptionOnMissing" value="false" />
</bean>

<bean id="configuration"
    class="org.springmodules.commons.configuration.CommonsConfigurationFactoryBean">
    <property name="configurations">
        <list>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean
    class="org.springframework.web.context.support.ServletContextPropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="systemPropertiesModeName" value="SYSTEM_PROPERTIES_MODE_OVERRIDE" />
    <property name="searchContextAttributes" value="true" />
    <property name="contextOverride" value="true" />
    <property name="ignoreResourceNotFound" value="true" />
    <property name="ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders" value="true" />
    <property name="properties" ref="configuration" />
</bean>

</beans>
```

In next project I have another spring-config.xml:

```
 <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
                       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
                       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
                       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">
<context:spring-configured />
<context:annotation-config />


<import resource="spring-hibernate.xml" />

</beans>
```

And spring-hibernate.xml:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
                       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
                       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
                       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
                       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
                       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd">
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />


<bean
    class="org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor" />


<bean id="dataSource"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">

    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/xxxxxxxxx" />
    <property name="username" value="root" />
    <property name="password" value="123456" />
</bean>


<bean id="hibernateSessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="xxx.xxx.domain"/>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">false</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.use_sql_comments">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.generate_statistics">false</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</prop>
        </props>
    </property> 
    <property name="namingStrategy" ref="namingStrategy"/>
</bean>

<bean id="hibernateConfiguration" factory-bean="&amp;hibernateSessionFactory"
    factory-method="getConfiguration" />

<bean id="namingStrategy" class="xxx.xxx.esp.domain.CustomNamingStrategy"/>

<bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="hibernateSessionFactory" />
</bean>

<context:component-scan base-package="xxx.xxx.dao"/>
<context:component-scan base-package="xxx.xxx.domain"/>

</beans>
```

Now we can go to web application and in web.xml:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
                  http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
version="3.0">

<context-param>
    <param-name>productionMode</param-name>
    <param-value>false</param-value>
</context-param>

<context-param>
    <param-name>heartbeatInterval</param-name>
    <param-value>10</param-value> <!-- 3 min -->
</context-param>

<context-param>
    <description>Spring context config location</description>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath*:spring-config.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
</listener>



<filter>
    <filter-name>SessionTimeoutCookieSettingFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>xxx.xxx.eDocuments.servlet.SessionTimeoutCookieSettingFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>vaadinWebAppServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>xxx.xxx.eDocuments.servlet.O4BWebAppServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>widgetset</param-name>
        <param-value>widgetset.xxxWidgetSet</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>UIProvider</param-name>
        <param-value>xxx.xxx.eDocuments.BaseSpringUIProvider</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>closeIdleSessions</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>captchaServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>nl.captcha.servlet.SimpleCaptchaServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>captcha-width</param-name>
        <param-value>200</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>captcha-height</param-name>
        <param-value>55</param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>vaadinWebAppServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>SessionTimeoutCookieSettingFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>captchaServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/captcha</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<session-config>
    <session-timeout>11</session-timeout>
</session-config>
</web-app>
```

And another spring-config.xml:

```
 <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util" xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/util
http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/task
http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.0.xsd">

<context:annotation-config />
<context:component-scan base-package="xxx.xxx" />
<context:spring-configured />

<import resource="classpath*:spring-remoting-o4b-service-importer.xml" />

<bean id="messageSource"
    class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8" />
    <property name="basenames">
        <list>
            <value>file:C:/xxxxxxxxx</value>
            <value>classpath:messages</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
</beans>
```

Sorry for this big config files here is last tomcat start log:

```
[localhost-startStop-1] INFO  org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader - Root WebApplicationContext: initialization started
[localhost-startStop-1] INFO  org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext - Refreshing Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Sun May 25 12:21:50 CEST 2014]; root of context hierarchy
[localhost-startStop-1] INFO  org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader - Loading XML bean definitions from URL [file:/C:/java/xxx/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/o4b-service-remote-impl/WEB-INF/classes/spring-config.xml]
[localhost-startStop-1] INFO  org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader - Loading XML bean definitions from URL [file:/C:/java/xxx/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/o4b-service-remote-impl/WEB-INF/classes/spring-remoting-o4b-service-exporter.xml]
[localhost-startStop-1] INFO  org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner - JSR-250 'javax.annotation.ManagedBean' found and supported for component scanning
[localhost-startStop-1] INFO  org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader - Loading XML bean definitions from URL [jar:file:/C:/java/xxx/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/o4b-service-remote-impl/WEB-INF/lib/o4b-domain-impl-orm-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/spring-hibernate.xml]
[localhost-startStop-1] INFO  org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner - JSR-250 'javax.annotation.ManagedBean' found and supported for component scanning
[localhost-startStop-1] INFO  org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner - JSR-250 'javax.annotation.ManagedBean' found and supported for component scanning
[localhost-startStop-1] INFO  org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader - Loading XML bean definitions from URL [jar:file:/C:/java/xxx/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/o4b-service-remote-impl/WEB-INF/lib/o4b-domain-impl-orm-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/spring-config.xml]
[localhost-startStop-1] INFO  org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader - Loading XML bean definitions from URL [jar:file:/C:/java/xxx/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/o4b-service-remote-impl/WEB-INF/lib/o4b-domain-impl-orm-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/spring-hibernate.xml]
[localhost-startStop-1] INFO  org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Overriding bean definition for bean 'dataSource': replacing [Generic bean: class [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null; defined in URL [jar:file:/C:/java/xxx/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/o4b-service-remote-impl/WEB-INF/lib/o4b-domain-impl-orm-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/spring-hibernate.xml]] with [Generic bean: class [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null; defined in URL [jar:file:/C:/java/xxx/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/o4b-service-remote-impl/WEB-INF/lib/o4b-domain-impl-orm-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/spring-hibernate.xml]]
[localhost-startStop-1] INFO  org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Overriding bean definition for bean 'hibernateSessionFactory': replacing [Generic bean: class [org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null; defined in URL [jar:file:/C:/java/xxx/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/o4b-service-remote-impl/WEB-INF/lib/o4b-domain-impl-orm-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/spring-hibernate.xml]] with [Generic bean: class [org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null; defined in URL [jar:file:/C:/java/xxx/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/o4b-service-remote-impl/WEB-INF/lib/o4b-domain-impl-orm-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/spring-hibernate.xml]]
[localhost-startStop-1] INFO  org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Overriding bean definition for bean 'hibernateConfiguration': replacing [Generic bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=&hibernateSessionFactory; factoryMethodName=getConfiguration; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null; defined in URL [jar:file:/C:/java/xxx/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/o4b-service-remote-impl/WEB-INF/lib/o4b-domain-impl-orm-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/spring-hibernate.xml]] with [Generic bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=&hibernateSessionFactory; factoryMethodName=getConfiguration; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null; defined in URL [jar:file:/C:/java/xxx/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/o4b-service-remote-impl/WEB-INF/lib/o4b-domain-impl-orm-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/spring-hibernate.xml]]
[localhost-startStop-1] INFO  org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Overriding bean definition for bean 'namingStrategy': replacing [Generic bean: class [xx.xxx.esp.domain.CustomNamingStrategy]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null; defined in URL [jar:file:/C:/java/xxx/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/o4b-service-remote-impl/WEB-INF/lib/o4b-domain-impl-orm-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/spring-hibernate.xml]] with [Generic bean: class [xx.xxx.esp.domain.CustomNamingStrategy]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null; defined in URL [jar:file:/C:/java/xxx/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/o4b-service-remote-impl/WEB-INF/lib/o4b-domain-impl-orm-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/spring-hibernate.xml]]
[localhost-startStop-1] INFO  org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Overriding bean definition for bean 'transactionManager': replacing [Generic bean: class [org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null; defined in URL [jar:file:/C:/java/xxx/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/o4b-service-remote-impl/WEB-INF/lib/o4b-domain-impl-orm-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/spring-hibernate.xml]] with [Generic bean: class [org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null; defined in URL [jar:file:/C:/java/xxx/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/o4b-service-remote-impl/WEB-INF/lib/o4b-domain-impl-orm-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/spring-hibernate.xml]]
[localhost-startStop-1] INFO  org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner - JSR-250 'javax.annotation.ManagedBean' found and supported for component scanning
[localhost-startStop-1] INFO  org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner - JSR-250 'javax.annotation.ManagedBean' found and supported for component scanning
[localhost-startStop-1] INFO  org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader - Loading XML bean definitions from URL [jar:file:/C:/java/xxx/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/o4b-service-remote-impl/WEB-INF/lib/o4b-messaging-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/spring-config.xml]
[localhost-startStop-1] INFO  org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader - Loading XML bean definitions from URL [jar:file:/C:/java/xxx/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/o4b-service-remote-impl/WEB-INF/lib/o4b-messaging-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/spring-jms-context.xml]
[localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG org.apache.xbean.spring.context.v2c.XBeanNamespaceHandler - Could not find resource: META-INF/services/org/apache/xbean/spring/http/activemq.apache.org/schema/core/broker
[localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG org.apache.xbean.spring.context.v2c.XBeanNamespaceHandler - Could not find resource: META-INF/services/org/apache/xbean/spring/http/activemq.apache.org/schema/core/transportConnector
[localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG org.apache.xbean.spring.context.v2c.XBeanNamespaceHandler - Could not find resource: META-INF/services/org/apache/xbean/spring/http/activemq.apache.org/schema/core/connectionFactory
[localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG org.apache.xbean.spring.context.v2c.XBeanNamespaceHandler - Could not find resource: META-INF/services/org/apache/xbean/spring/http/activemq.apache.org/schema/core/redeliveryPolicy
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/java/xxx/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/o4b-service-remote-impl/WEB-INF/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.5.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/java/xxx/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/o4b-service-remote-impl/WEB-INF/lib/slf4j-simple-1.7.6.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory]
[localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG org.apache.commons.configuration.ConfigurationUtils - ConfigurationUtils.locate(): base is C:\java\xxx\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\o4b-service-remote-impl\WEB-INF\classes, name is configuration.xml
[localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG org.apache.commons.configuration.DefaultFileSystem - Could not locate file configuration.xml at C:\java\xxx\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\o4b-service-remote-impl\WEB-INF\classes: unknown protocol: c
[localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG org.apache.commons.configuration.ConfigurationUtils - Loading configuration from the path C:\java\xxx\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\o4b-service-remote-impl\WEB-INF\classes\configuration.xml
[localhost-startStop-1] INFO  xxx.xxx.applicationCommons.spring.SpringXMLConfiguration - Configuration is loading: configuration.xml
[localhost-startStop-1] INFO  org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer - Loading properties file from class path resource [jms-default.properties]
[localhost-startStop-1] INFO  org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer - Loading properties file from URL [jar:file:/C:/java/xxx/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/o4b-service-remote-impl/WEB-INF/lib/o4b-jms-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/jms.properties]
[localhost-startStop-1] INFO  org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource - Loaded JDBC driver: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
[localhost-startStop-1] INFO  org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext - Bean 'dataSource' of type [class org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
[localhost-startStop-1] INFO  org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext - Bean 'namingStrategy' of type [class xxx.xxx.esp.domain.CustomNamingStrategy] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
[localhost-startStop-1] INFO  org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean - Building new Hibernate SessionFactory
[localhost-startStop-1] INFO  org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext - Bean 'hibernateSessionFactory' of type [class org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
[localhost-startStop-1] INFO  org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@efd84f: defining beans [org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalPersistenceAnnotationProcessor,BPMNProcessServiceRemoteImpl,dictionaryServiceRemoteImpl,invoiceServiceRemoteImpl,notificationServiceRemoteImpl,authenticationServiceRemoteImpl,authorizationServiceRemoteImpl,passwordGeneratorServiceRemoteImpl,permissionServiceRemoteImpl,templateServiceRemoteImpl,usersServiceRemoteImpl,addressFactoryImpl,billingPlanFactoryImpl,contactFactoryImpl,dictionaryFactoryImpl,nodeFactoryImpl,partnerFactoryImpl,permissionResourceFactoryImpl,roleFactoryImpl,phoneNumberFactoryImpl,pointOfSaleFactoryImpl,organizatoinSharedDataFactoryImpl,personSharedDataFactoryImpl,userFactoryImpl,addressDaoImpl,contactDaoImpl,nodeDaoImpl,partnerDaoImpl,roleDaoImpl,phoneNumberDaoImpl,pointOfSaleDaoImpl,userDaoImpl,addressRepositoryImpl,contactRepositoryImpl,nodeRepositoryImpl,partnerRepositoryImpl,phoneNumberRepositoryImpl,pointOfSaleRepositoryImpl,roleRepositoryImpl,userRepositoryImpl,BPMNProcessServiceInternalImpl,BPMNProcessServiceImpl,dictionaryServiceImpl,invoiceServiceImpl,DTODomainMapperFacade,notificationServiceImpl,passwordGeneratorServiceImpl,authenticationServiceImpl,authorizationServiceImpl,permissionServiceImpl,templateServiceImpl,usersServiceImpl,org.springframework.remoting.rmi.RmiServiceExporter#0,org.springframework.remoting.rmi.RmiServiceExporter#1,org.springframework.remoting.rmi.RmiServiceExporter#2,org.springframework.remoting.rmi.RmiServiceExporter#3,org.springframework.remoting.rmi.RmiServiceExporter#4,org.springframework.remoting.rmi.RmiServiceExporter#5,org.springframework.remoting.rmi.RmiServiceExporter#6,org.springframework.remoting.rmi.RmiServiceExporter#7,org.springframework.remoting.rmi.RmiServiceExporter#8,org.springframework.remoting.rmi.RmiServiceExporter#9,org.springframework.aop.config.internalAutoProxyCreator,org.springframework.transaction.annotation.AnnotationTransactionAttributeSource#0,org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor#0,org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAdvisor,org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor#0,dataSource,hibernateSessionFactory,hibernateConfiguration,namingStrategy,transactionManager,xmlConfigurationDefault,configuration,org.springframework.web.context.support.ServletContextPropertyPlaceholderConfigurer#0,org.springframework.context.config.internalBeanConfigurerAspect,org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor#1,org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer#0,jmsBroker,jmsConnectionFactory,connectionFactory,org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.importAwareProcessor]; root of factory hierarchy
[localhost-startStop-1] INFO  org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager - Using DataSource [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource@a4667b] of Hibernate SessionFactory for HibernateTransactionManager
[localhost-startStop-1] INFO  xxx.xxx.jms.configuration.CustomPersistenceAdapterFactory - Creating default broker service persistence adapter : KahaDBPersistenceAdapter[C:\java\eclipse\activemq-data\KahaDB] (No data source specified)
[localhost-startStop-1] ERROR org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerService - Memory Usage for the Broker (1024 mb) is more than the maximum available for the JVM: 247 mb - resetting to 70% of maximum available: 173 mb
[localhost-startStop-1] WARN  org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerService - Store limit is 102400 mb, whilst the data directory: C:\java\eclipse\activemq-data\KahaDB only has 69186 mb of usable space - resetting to maximum available disk space: 69186 mb
[localhost-startStop-1] INFO  org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader - Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 8624 ms
```

Please help me

Comment: And why do you think it's not "starting"?

Comment: i don't have any idea why, because this should work, but isn't

Comment: I'm not sure you've tested if the actual filter is being called or not. If you know the filter is called and it finds the bean in your context, you know the problem lies somewhere else.

Comment: filter is not called because if i change filter-class or anything else in this filler i'm not getting any error

Comment: Changing the class doesn't prove anything. You should set a break point in the doFilter() method and see if it hits

Comment: problem solved, i had to add @Transactional annotation on my dao